# Run a c-programm on startup and see echo via ssh on Raspberry Pi

Tags: linux, ssh, startup, raspberry-pi

I have found many ways of starting a script or program when booting Linux, but none of the options is sufficient for what I am looking for:

- I have a Raspberry Pi running raspbian wheezy
- I have a compiled c-program which creates echo-outputs from time to time
- I would like the program to run on startup of the pi *and* be able to connect via ssh and see what is going on in the program (get echo-live-output, not only a log-file).

Is there any way of achieving this?

Comment: Can't you do a `less logfile` and then press Shift+f?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone encountering a similar problem: I solved it the following way:

I created a startup-bash-script including

```
sudo /foo/main.o | tee /foo/log;
```

which writes the output into a log-file. Since the output is created in an infinity-loop, one has to make sure to include a `fflush(stdout);` after every `printf()`

Then I can monitor the log-file by using

```
tail -f /foo/log
```

Answer (score 0):

To run the program at startup, put it in the root `crontab` and use the `@reboot` option.  Why don't you want to redirect the output to a log file?  Then you can monitor it's output in many ways (eg. using scp).

Comment: I did not know that monitoring was possible and it did not work in the beginning because of the missing `fflush(stdout);` which prevented the output from being written to the log-file